# Three.js | applying texture from Blender model

Tags: three.js, textures, blender

I'm using a free 3d model from turbosquid. This model is using a texture that looks like this:

[image: texture]

It does look good in Blender:

[image: blender_render]

But once exported to three.js, it seems that the texture does not follow the uv map:

[image: three_render]

Here is the code i'm using:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load('json/Ship.json', function ( geometry, materials ) {
        ship = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materials[0]);
        scene.add(ship);
    }
);
```

And here is the json I get once exported from Blender:

[image: json]

What am I missing?
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You normally don't need to load the textures manually. Try to create your mesh like this `ship = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materials[0]);`. So don't create a new material but use the parameter of the callback.

Comment: @Mugen87 You're absolutly right, I've edited my question that it's less confusing. I still get the same result though :/

Comment: Can you make a try with this [GLTFExporter](https://github.com/Kupoman/blendergltf). You can use [GLTFLoader](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js) in order to load the asset. The JSON Blender exporter is somewhat buggy...

Comment: @Mugen87 The GLTFExporter gives me this error : "three.min.js:480 THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D.". I cant find a way to properly export the scene from Blender, what could I be missing?

Comment: Are you able to share the `.blend` file? May want to try [KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter/) as well.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy Here it is: https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/free-sample-fighter-3d-model/798902. I'm guessing if I have a problem with a model using two different loaders, it might have something to do with the model itself...

Answer (score 0):

There are some minor complexities in this model, which I think are causing issues for Blender exporters. They're not "wrong", but they're hard for exporters to handle without cleanup. You can fix those manually (open the `.blend` file in Blender, apply modifiers, remove all textures except the diffuse) but the easiest path is probably converting the OBJ version provided by Turbosquid to glTF. Going to the [Cesium OBJ->glTF converter](https://cesiumjs.org/convertmodel.html) (or OBJ2GLTF if you need something programmatic) and dragging in the OBJ/MTL/texture will give the right result. *NOTE: you'll need to move the `sh3.jpg` file into the same directory as the MTL file; it shouldn't be in the `Textures/` folder.*

Result on https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/ — using three.js r92 and THREE.GLTFLoader.

[image]